# How to decode JSON that is an array of arrays (of multiple types) in Swift with AlamoFire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, decodable

I am trying to get JSON from an external source, using AlamoFire tools.  Using the .responseJSON method works, but that will be deprecated and in any case I know .responseDecodable is more sound.  However, I cannot figure out how to model the data so it will decode.  Here is the returned JSON:

```
{
    p = 1668147588893;
    q =     {
        cue =         (
                        (
                1667442513807,
                                {
                    done = 0;
                    link = new;
                    share = 0;
                    tags = new;
                    title = new;
                }
            ),
                        (
                1667442494796,
                                {
                    done = 0;
                    link = "~.new";
                    share = 0;
                    tags = new;
                    title = new;
                }
            ),
                        (
                1667441502089,
                                {
                    done = 1;
                    link = "~.s";
                    share = 0;
                    tags = s;
                    title = gogogo;
                }
            )
);
};
}
```

I am working on the model, but cannot figure out how to deal with the first element of each underlying item having no key value.  Otherwise I think this would be trivially easy.  I'm sure there must be some way to use init and a custom decoder, but I cannot figure it out.  So far I just have:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let p: Int
    let q: CueFeed
}

struct CueFeed: Decodable {
    let cue: [CueItem]
}
```

But I don't know how to write the struct for CueItem.

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted proper json.

Comment: could you add this `print("\n \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) as AnyObject) \n")` just after you get the data, and show us what it prints.

Comment: According to your NSDictionary dump the JSON cannot be decoded with the synthesized decoding method because the inner array of `CueItem` is heterogenous, it contains one `String` or `Int` item and one dictionary. You have to implement custom `init(decoder` and decode `UnkeyedContainer`.